# Why can't I run the WWDC app?

Tags: ipad, developer-program

Today when I tried to use the WWDC app (version 5.0.1) on my iPad, I got a message saying that this version is no longer supported, and I need to get an update from the App Store.  But when I go to the App Store, it is not offering any update for the WWDC app.  What gives?  Maybe it's a temporary delay in posting a new version, or maybe there's a new version that does not run on my 3rd-generation iPad (iOS 9.3.5)?

Comment: Please edit in your post what version of iOS is running on your iPad and what version of the app you have installed. It's likely the changes this week killed the server side infrastructure for older versions of the app but it's hard to know without details to confirm.

Comment: That, plus iPad 3rd gen is maximum iOS 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Apple, but this is likely an intentional decision to walk away from the server side / api calls for the older version of the WWDC app.

One of the core messages for iOS 11 is that all 32 bit platforms and apps are done for developers, and Apple making a hard stop of functionality (programming in a message telling you your app is too old). Programming in a kill switch could be seen as reinforcing that experience for developers.

The temporary good news is despite this move, you can still watch WWDC 2017 content on iOS 9 in Safari. The news on 64 bit only requirements was covered in the Platforms State of the Union keynote (2017 session 102) I believe.

Comment: This is correct. It's mentioned within the first 5 mins of Session 102, Platforms State of the Union, with more details provided later in the session. The move is happening across the board, iOS, macOS etc. In fact macOS High Sierra will be the last macOS version to support 32-bit apps.

Comment: @Monomeeth, to be precise, the Platforms State of the Union said that High Sierra will be the last macOS version to support 32-bit apps "without compromises".

Comment: No need to confuse the matter with discussions about 32 vs. 64 bit. It's now a requirement for apps to support both, yes, but since the new WWDC app runs fine on 32-bit platforms it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the news that some 32 bit versions of the app still function. I’ve edited to explain my main point is Apple is walking the walk with its own apps. Programming in alets to explain when an app version is no longer operational.

Comment: No problem. I would still argue that Apple time and time again tells developers to "support the two latest versions of iOS", and that they're doing exactly that, albeit a bit eagerly. They just don't care enough about reaching developers that can't keep up and are still on iOS 9 or on old hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You're not shown the update to the WWDC app as it [requires iOS 10.3](https://appsto.re/at/w0kkM.i) but you indicated you're running iOS 9. Just update iOS and the app.

Comment: OP's iPad maxes out at iOS 9.3.5, unfortunately.

Comment: This actually answers the question. I don't know why the accepted answer is talking about platform word sizes. It has nothing to do with this whatsoever.